# GIT forces pull of previously pushed changes

Tags: git

I'm new to GIT so I might be missing something simple.  But the problem is as follows:

- I created a whole new Git repository on Remote server (using Bonobo server)
- Cloned the repository on local machine
- Created branch (i.e. git checkout -b ticket1)
- Set up upstream for branch (i.e. git push -u origin ticket1)
- Started working on project
- Committed changes
- Pushed changes (plain git push)
- Repeated making updates/commit/push process two more times
- Did more updates and committed
- On push, push failed saying I'm behind 2 commits so I need to do git pull

The above seems weird to me as first, I'm the only person doing any changes/updates and when I do the git pull, the commits fetched are my previous commits.  I'm confused on what is going on, am I doing something wrong, why is git saying I have to pull my previous changes?

Comment: In the second to last step, most likely you rewrote some commits, perhaps by amending existing commits, or rebasing, or even resetting back 2 commits and making new ones. Does that sound like what you did? Also, you should look to see what those 2 commits are: `git log @ @{u} --graph` will show you your local branch and the remote branch and the relationship between them.

Comment: You're "lying". Not on purpose, but you've left out some important piece of information. It would be better if, instead of talking about your commands, you actually copied and paste into your question the actual transcript of what you said to Git and what Git replied to you.

Comment: @TTT, I have not done any rebase or resets.  The command does show that the remote and local diverged before the pull (not sure why though).  I'll keep this in mind if it happens again (hopefully not), then again, I might be doing something wrong

Comment: @matt, I apologize, I do not the transcript with me anymore (kind of closed the git bash window) and you are totally correct that would have been more helpful (rookie mistake there)

Comment: @JCFC There are multiple ways you could have done it, including amending commits, or maybe you switched branches and pushed to the same remote branch? Also, you can likely answer your own "not sure why" by just looking at what the remote commits are. Maybe the message and timing will help you realize what you did.

Comment: The point is, it is totally possible to do something that causes the remote to object that you can't push until you pull. But you have not told us what _you_ did that caused that.

Comment: @matt and TTT, thanks for the help, it seems I might have identified where issue is happening.  I'm developing with Eclipse and Eclipse Git integration seems to be spamming calls to the GIt remote server.  I'll check there and see what is going on

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. So maybe someone other than you (Eclipse) has been committing to the remote.

Comment: It's useful to know that Eclipse uses egit, its own separate Git implementation that uses jgit, a Java-language implementation of Git. There are differences, both subtle and occasionally large and glaring, between jgit and "cgit" (the C version of Git from the core Git team). It sounds like Eclipse has one of those glaring ones here.

Comment: The two separate development teams have some crossover, and some good stuff happens first on the jgit side: I recently learned that the long-neglected reftables implementation that's been very, very slowly going into cgit over the last two or three years actually comes from jgit. Reftables are sorely needed in cgit for several reasons, but they're not there yet (in cgit).